# Linear equation with residue classes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modular-arithmetic

I'm having a hard time solving an exercise that seems fairly easy:

Given a linear map 
$$ f: (Z/5)^2 \mapsto (Z/5)^2 $$ 
and 
$$ f(\bar{2}, \bar{3}) = (\bar{1},\bar{1})$$
$$f(\bar{1}, \bar{4}) = (\bar{3}, \bar{3})$$

calculate $f(x,y)$.

I know I have to describe $\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}$ as a linear combination of the two function arguments.

$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix} \bar{2} \\ \bar{3} \end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix} \bar{1} \\ \bar{4} \end{pmatrix}$$

Then I end up with the following system of linear equations:
$$ x = \bar{2}a + b \rightarrow a = \bar{3}(x - b)$$
$$ y = \bar{3}a + \bar{4}b$$

Replace a in the second equation: 
$$ y = \bar{3}(\bar{3}(x -b)) + \bar{4}b =$$
$$ y = \bar{4}(x -b) + \bar{4}b =$$
$$ y = \bar{4}x - \bar{4}b + \bar{4}b = (\text{or } y = \bar{4}x + b + \bar{4}b) ? =$$
$$ y= \bar{4}x$$

Which doesn't get me any further. I'm not sure if $\bar{4}(x - b) = \bar{4}x + b$ since $\bar{4} * -1 = -4 = \bar{1}$ or if it's simply $ \bar{4}(x + b) = \bar{4}x +\bar{4}b$. Either way I end up with $y = \bar{4}x$.

Or maybe I'm interpreting this the wrong way?

Comment: You have a problem, $\overline{2}\cdot (\overline{1},\overline{4}) = (\overline{2},\overline{3})$, the vectors whose image you are given are linearly dependent. $f$ is underspecified.

Comment: I thought that was the problem but I wasn't sure. This is copied 1:1 from my exercises so I guess it's a typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not enough information. I will ommit the bars, since we are making nothing with 'authentic' integers. The set $\{(2,3),(1,4)\}$ is not linearly independent, that is, it's not a basis:
$$\left|
\begin{array}{r}
2&3\\
1&4
\end{array}
\right|=8-3=5=0$$

so there are infinitely many linear functions that satisfy the requirements.

May this one be a trapped exercise ;)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the comment before posting the answer. I leave it undeleted in case of the determinat approach may be useful for anybody.